# Tests: --group laravel equivalent in angular?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

Is there a way to group tests in Angular? I am currently running my tests using Jasmine. In Laravel you are able run test like `php artisan test --group my-section-group`. This test will run only a subsection with group defined as `@group my-section-group`

This functionality is very useful especially in debugging why a particular test is failing. Is this functionality or equivalent available in Angular Testing.

Currently I have to use `fdescribe` and `fit` to run particular tests and `xdescribe` and `xit` to omit particular tests. The problem with this approach is that each time I have to go through my code changing these to be able to run all tests

It would be great if I there exists something like below that would run all test marked with login group

```sh
ng test --group login
```

Is there such a functionality/ Can such a functionality be implemented?

Comment: there is an include option for this command. you could try to `ng test --include my-header*.spec.ts`

Comment: @Andrei thanks for the suggestion, this will be very helpful especially for projects organized in features